# How to find compare two array based on the minimum length of the array python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I want to compare two array such that i have to compare two arrays based on the index position such that arr2[i] in arr1[i:]. If the lenght of the array is equal it is easy, both the arrays can have the minimum length, could you please help me how to dynamically find the minimum lenght of the array in the loop?

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]
arr2 = [4,5,6]

for i in range(min(arr1,arr2)):
   if minimum_arr[i] in max_arr[i:].
```

---> how to dynamically solve this issue, please help.

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand your problem, you better set the `minimum_arr` and the `max_arr` before the for loop. I would like to notice that the indexing of lists starts with 0, which means that the statement you gave will never be True with these lists, so I fixed the issue in the if statement (you do not need to get an nth element of the `max_arr`, since you want to check if the given element is in that list or not).

```
    arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
    arr2 = [4, 5, 6]

    minimum_arr = arr1 if len(arr1) < len(arr2) else arr2
    max_arr = arr1 if len(arr1) > len(arr2) else arr2

    for i in range(len(minimum_arr)):
        if minimum_arr[i] in max_arr:
            # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would determine which list is the shorter before entering the loop. You can do this by sorting a list of the two lists by there length, using the built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) setting the `key` argument to the `len` function.

Then you code would look like:

```py
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]
arr2 = [4,5,6]

# Sort the two arrays by length
short_arr, long_arr = sorted([arr1, arr2], key=len)
for i in range(len(short_arr)):
    if short_arr[i] in long_arr[i:]:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` instead of range to get the current object and the index you're at currently as you iterate the smaller list. As for getting the smaller list you need to use the `key` argument and I also suggest using `sorted` instead of using `min` and `max`.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]
list2 = [4,5,6]

min_list, max_list = sorted([list1, list2], key=len)
for i, n in enumerate(min_list):
   if n in max_list[i:]:
       ...
```